# Slice error when using MultiRNNCell

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using MultiRNNCell from `tensorflow.models.rnn.rnn_cell`. This is how declare my MultiRNNCell

**Code:**

`e_cell = rnn_cell.GRUCell(self.rnn_size)`

`e_cell = rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([e_cell] * 2)`

Later on I use it from inside seq2seq.embedding_rnn_decoder as follows

`ouputs, mem_states = seq2seq.embedding_rnn_decoder(decoder_inputs, enc_state, e_cell, vocab_size, output_projection=(W, b), feed_previous=False)#`

On doing this I get the following error

**Error:**

`tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: Expected size[1] in [0, 0], but got 1024
         [[Node: en/embedding_rnn_decoder_1/rnn_decoder/MultiRNNCell/Cell1/Slice = Slice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](Sigmoid_2, en/embedding_rnn_decoder_1/rnn_decoder/MultiRNNCell/Cell1/Slice/begin, en/embedding_rnn_decoder_1/rnn_decoder/MultiRNNCell/Cell1/Slice/size)]]
         [[Node: en/embedding_rnn_decoder/rnn_decoder/loop_function_17/StopGradient/_1230 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_11541_en/embedding_rnn_decoder/rnn_decoder/loop_function_17/StopGradient", tensor_type=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]`

Has anyone seen a similar error? Any pointers?

Comment: See here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38183276/tensorflow-rnn-slice-error

Answer (score 0):

Seem like an invalid argument into embedding_rnn_decoder. 
Maybe try to change enc_state:

`ouputs, mem_states = seq2seq.embedding_rnn_decoder(decoder_inputs, enc_state[-1], e_cell, vocab_size, output_projection=(W, b), feed_previous=False)`

Answer (score 0):

I've got a problem similar to yours.`{tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: Expected size[1] in [0, 0], but got 40}`
I also use `rnn_cell.GRUCell(self.rnn_size)`
I want to share my experience ,maybe it's helpful.
Here is how I fixed it.
I want to use gru cell and basic rnn cell ,so I adapt the programme from others which is coded for lstm cell.
The different between lstm and GRU/BasicRnn is the state_size.
Here is lstm cell`def state_size(self):return 2 * self._num_units`
Here is GRU/BasicRnn cell `def state_size(self):return self._num_units`
Therefore the shape of matrix is different,and the tensor is not suit for the op.I advice you to check your code contains `tf.slice`

Comment: Can you please improve your answer's formatting? It's very hard to read

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the embedding_rnn_seq2seq (Tensorflow v0.9.0). I switched my inputs around to run with the embedding_rnn_decoder and was able to run a session with these inputs.

```
enc_inp = [tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(batch_size,),
           name="inp%i" % t) for t in range(seq_length)]

labels = [tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(batch_size,),
           name="labels%i" % t) for t in range(seq_length)]

weights = [tf.ones_like(labels_t, dtype=tf.float32) for labels_t in labels]

dec_inp = ([tf.zeros_like(enc_inp[0], dtype=np.int32, name="GO")] + enc_inp[:-1])

prev_mem = tf.zeros((batch_size, memory_dim))

cell = rnn_cell.GRUCell(memory_dim)
cell = rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([cell]*2)

dec_outputs, mem_states = seq2seq.embedding_rnn_decoder(dec_inp, prev_mem, 
cell, n_x, n_y,feed_previous=True)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This problem is occurring because you have doubled your GRU cell but your initial vector is not doubled. 
If your initial_vector size is [batch_size,50].

Then initial_vector = tf.concat(1,[initial_vector,initial_vector])

Now input this to decoder as initial vector.