# Tensorflow RNN slice error

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I am attempting to create a multilayered RNN using LSTMs in tensorflow. I am using Tensorflow version 0.9.0 and python 2.7 on Ubuntu 14.04.

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: Expected begin[1] in [0, 2000], but got 4000
```

when I use

```
rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([cell]*num_layers)
```

if num_layers is greater than 1.

My code:

```
size = 1000
config.forget_bias = 1
and config.num_layers = 3
cell = rnn_cell.LSTMCell(size,forget_bias=config.forget_bias)
cell_layers = rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([cell]*config.num_layers)
```

I would also like to be able to switch to using GRU cells but this gives me the same error:

```
Expected begin[1] in [0, 1000], but got 2000
```

I have tried explicitly setting

```
num_proj = 1000
```

which also did not help.

Is this something to do with my use of concatenated states? As I have attempted to set

```
state_is_tuple=True
```

which gives:

```
`ValueError: Some cells return tuples of states, but the flag state_is_tuple is not set.  State sizes are: [LSTMStateTuple(c=1000, h=1000), LSTMStateTuple(c=1000, h=1000), LSTMStateTuple(c=1000, h=1000)]`
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why this worked but, I added in a dropout wrapper. i.e.

```
if Training:
    cell = rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(cell,output_keep_prob=config.keep_prob)
```

And now it works.
This works for both LSTM and GRU cells.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is occurring because you have increased layer of  your GRU cell but your initial vector is not doubled. If your initial_vector size is [batch_size,50].

Then initial_vector = tf.concat(1,[initial_vector]*num_layers)

Now input this to decoder as initial vector.